# Why does \renewcommand{ ... }{ ... } not work with \section (or \subsection)?

Tags: sectioning, errors, renewcommand, unnumbered-sections

I have a super simple document, and I'm using pdfLaTeX on Windows 10 with MiKTeX.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
    \section{Some section heading}
    Some body text
\end{document}
```

This works, but I'd like to hide the "numbers" before my section heading. Sadly, my real document has quite a few of these, so I can't easily do it by hand. So, I add `\renewcommand{\section}{\section*}` after my `\documentclass` in hopes that I can redefine `\section` as `\section*`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\section}{\section*}

\begin{document}
    \section{Some section heading}
    Some body text
\end{document}
```

But, when I try this, I get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]. \section`

When I manually do the replacement, it compiles fine, but I'd like to avoid using Find + Replace here, so how can I do this with `\renewcommand` (or a different command that does this)?

Comment: why don't you use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}`?

Answer (score 7):

`\section*` is `\section *`  the command looks for a `*` it is not part of the name, so you have programmed a non terminating loop

`\section` -> `\section*` -> `\section**` ->...

eventually you have 10000 `*` flooding the input buffer stack and get the error you showed.